# Oracle ADF UserActivityInfo usage

Tags: oracle, user-interface, oracle-adf

There is oracle.adf.view.rich.monitoring.UserActivityInfo.
Documentation says it is used to record end user details.
Can somebody show me its usage through a code snippet.

Comment: I don't think there is anything available on this class usage, apart of an API description. Seems like part of a project that died early. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wish to log the UI clicks/activity performed by end user on my ADF project. ClickHistory in ADF does it and it uses this UserActivityInfo. I wish to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need a clientListener next to every button, link, selectOneChoice component you need to monitor.

You can find some example, here: http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/websocket-integration-with-adf-for-ppr.html

PS: I have implemented this in a generic fashion for our: http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/red-samurai-adf-performance-audit-tool.html
But I can't suggest such approach, as it is specific to each version of ADF and it requires lots of work.

Comment: Adding clientlistener for every component in product would take ages.
Can you please tell what is the generic approach you took.

Comment: please check my post on ADF EMG https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adf-methodology/Q-oQ25uDRG4

Comment: I read your post Thanks.
You have mentioned:
"We did this in generic fashion, changing the HTML response generated by ADF at runtime."

 I need to know.. How you did it. :)

Comment: You can use a ServletFilter for altering generated HTML response.

Comment: Your solution looks feasible. I will try it out.

Comment: Since you have already done it can you share some code snippet :)

Comment: Florin, this might be helpful:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/adf-web-deploying.htm#ADFFD22071

For End User Monitoring